# Error creating several recursive m2m relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I need to store the relations between people. So I have the following models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonRelationship', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name="person_parents_set")
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonRelationship', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name="person_friends_set") 

class PersonRelationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="from_persons")
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="to_persons")
    relation_start = models.DateField(blank=True)
    relation_end = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

When I try to syncdb I get this error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
films.person: The model Person has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model PersonRelationship, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.
```

I guess I cannot have two m2m relationships trough the same model, so I tried to create a model for each type of relation, to avoid repeating myself I used a abstract model like this:

```
class PersonRelationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="from_persons")
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="to_persons")
    relation_start = models.DateField(blank=True)
    relation_end = models.DateField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PersonParent(PersonRelationship):
    pass 

class PersonFriend(PersonRelationship):
    pass
```

And I'm getting this error, but I already have a related_name:

```
films.personparent: Accessor for field 'from_person' clashes with related field     'Person.from_persons'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'from_person'.
films.personparent: Reverse query name for field 'from_person' clashes with related field    'Person.from_persons'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'from_person'.
films.personparent: Accessor for field 'from_person' clashes with related field 'Person.from_persons'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'from_person'.
films.personparent: Reverse query name for field 'from_person' clashes with related field 'Person.from_persons'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'from_person'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, I am posting it in case somebody coming from google had found the same issue.

Read this link [link updated to v1.9]:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

So I just changed the related name to:

```
from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_from_persons")
to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_to_persons")
```