# Django ORM spouse, children, parent relationships

Tags: django, orm, foreign-key-relationship, relationships

I have a model called Person and a person may or may not have several relationship; spouse, children, parents. If the Person has a spouse, but that spouse isn't a person in the database, I want to be able to keep the spouse as just a string value and not another Person. Because of that I assume I need a `through` model specified on the m2m relationships:

```python
class Person(models.Model):
    spouse = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship')
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship')
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship')

class Relationship(models.Model):
    personA = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    personB = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True)
    person_name = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    relationship = models.CharField(choices=(('s', 'spouse'),
                                             ('c', 'child'),
                                             ('p', 'parent')),
                                    default='s')
```

When I try to run the ./manage.py migrate I get the following error messages showing up:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
myapp.person: Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables cannot be symmetrical.
myapp.person: Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables cannot be symmetrical.
myapp.person: The model Person has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model Relationship, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.
myapp.person: Many-to-many fields with intermediate tables cannot be symmetrical.
myapp.person: The model Person has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model Relationship, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.
myapp.relationship: Accessor for field 'personA' clashes with related field 'Person.relationship_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'personA'.
myapp.relationship: Accessor for field 'personB' clashes with related field 'Person.relationship_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'personB'.
```

**Obviously** I'm doing it wrong.

**How can I specify relationships between the same model with extra data associated with that relationship?**

**Alternatively, how else might you structure these models to keep track of the same data?**

Comment: Why not stub them in as a user?

Comment: They are not users. They are authors, illustrators, etc. and are also related to books, film, etc.

Comment: Sorry, why not stub them in as [insert whatever model you're using here] instead of a string?

Comment: If I understand what your saying, why don't I just create an instance for the spouse (for example) that just has the name fields filled out?

If that is what you are suggesting, the reason I don't want to do that is that I don't want to clutter up the Person table with people that didn't contribute in anyway to the works (books, film, etc) of which I'm keeping track. I don't want to have all of the author's spouses also searchable in the database. I just want the fact that they have a spouse and what their name is if they haven't published anything of their own.

Comment: You can exclude those results if you like. For me, that seems like the cleanest solution (stub Person  records) rather than leaving it up to the M2M relationship to hang onto that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error creating several recursive m2m relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948401/error-creating-several-recursive-m2m-relationships?rq=1) seems like a related question. I realized that I could get the same effect by removing the `parents`, `children`, `spouse` fields from the `Person` model and setting the related_name to `relationships` on the `Relationship` model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    [ other fields ]

class Relationship(models.Model):
    personA = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='relationships')
    personB = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True)
    person_name = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    relationship = models.CharField(choices=(('s', 'spouse'),
                                             ('c', 'child'),
                                             ('p', 'parent')),
                                    default='s')
```

I haven't tested it yet, but it does validate and doesn't throw the error messages any more. This also seems cleaner.

I imagine I could create some properties on the `Person` model to give me access to say `Person.spouse` which returns all `Person.relationships` where the `relationship == 's'`.

Comment: This does work. I've since done similar things in similar situations and this solution works great.